# sp_executeSQL para cada registro de uma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

tenho o seguinte problema:

preciso analisar as diferenças entre dois bancos de dados, com base nas tabelas existentes e colunas dentro destas tabelas. Minha ideia é pegar o nome das colunas dentro do INFORMATION_SCHEMA de cada banco e com base em cada tabela, inserir um registro em uma tabela temporária assim

```
--CREATE VARS FROM DATABASES AND TSQL
DECLARE @C AS VARCHAR(50), @F AS VARCHAR(50), @S AS VARCHAR(MAX);

--SET DB'S
SET @C = ''; --GOOD DB
SET @F = ''; --BAD DB

--GET @C TABLE NAMES AND INSERT IN #C_TABLES
SELECT UPPER(TABLE_NAME) AS TABELA INTO #C_TABLES FROM @C.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

--GET @F TABLE NAMES AND INSERT IN #F_TABLES
SELECT UPPER(TABLE_NAME) AS TABELA INTO #F_TABLES FROM @F.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

Meu problema é que não sei como utilizar um **sp_executeSQL** buscando as colunas a cada registro existente nas tabelas que criei anteriormente `#C_TABLES` e `#F_TABLES`...

Alguém ai pode me dar uma luz por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Comparação "manual" da estrutura

Não precisa de SQL dinâmico, pelo menos no caso de você saber os nomes dos bancos de dados.

Para identificar tabelas que existem em um e não existem no outro, ou vice-versa, use a seguinte query:

```
-- check tables
SELECT T1.TABLE_NAME 'DB1 TABLE', T2.TABLE_NAME 'DB2 TABLE'
FROM BANCO_A.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T1 
FULL JOIN BANCO_B.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T2 
    ON T1.TABLE_NAME = T2.TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY ISNULL(T1.TABLE_NAME, T2.TABLE_NAME)
```

Para comparar os campos e tipos, pode usar esta outra:

```
-- check tables and columns
SELECT DB1.TABLE_NAME 'DB1 TABLE', DB1.COLUMN_NAME 'DB1 COLUMN', DB1.DATA_TYPE 'DB1 TYPE',
    DB2.TABLE_NAME 'DB2 TABLE', DB2.COLUMN_NAME 'DB1 COLUMN', DB2.DATA_TYPE 'DB2 TYPE'
FROM (
    SELECT T1.TABLE_NAME, C1.COLUMN_NAME, C1.DATA_TYPE
    FROM BANCO_A.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T1 
    JOIN BANCO_A.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1 
        ON C1.TABLE_NAME = T1.TABLE_NAME
    ) DB1
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT T2.TABLE_NAME, C2.COLUMN_NAME, C2.DATA_TYPE
    FROM BANCO_B.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T2 
    JOIN BANCO_B.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2 
        ON C2.TABLE_NAME = T2.TABLE_NAME
    ) DB2
    ON DB1.TABLE_NAME = DB2.TABLE_NAME
    AND DB1.COLUMN_NAME = DB2.COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY ISNULL(DB1.TABLE_NAME, DB2.TABLE_NAME), ISNULL(DB1.COLUMN_NAME, DB2.COLUMN_NAME)
```

O que essas consultas basicamente fazem é usar o `FULL JOIN` para e cruzar a estrutura de duas tabelas, exibindo o que tem em uma e não tem na outra.

Seria possível ainda adicionar algumas cláusulas `WHERE` para filtrar somente os campos ou tabelas que estão diferentes.

Para definir quais bases você quer comparar, basta alterar o prefixo nos trechos `BANCO_A.INFORMATION_SCHEMA` e `BANCO_B.INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

## Usando SQL dinâmico

Se, entretanto, você quer fazer uma rotina genérica e precisa mesmo executar consultas dinâmicas, use variáveis do tipo `NVARCHAR` e monte sua consulta primeiro.

O comando `SP_SQLEXEC` tem problemas com valores do tipo `VARCHAR` e também não aceita que você faça a concatenação direto na passagem de argumentos. Não sei se isso vale para todas as versões do SQL Server, mas geralmente é o que causa mais dificuldades com esses comandos.

O seguinte exemplo executa a primeira query acima, que compara as tabelas de dois bancos:

```
-- check tables
DECLARE 
    @BANCO1 NVARCHAR(100) = 'BANCO_A',
    @BANCO2 NVARCHAR(100) = 'BANCO_B',
    @SQL NVARCHAR(2000)

SET @SQL = N'SELECT T1.TABLE_NAME ''DB1 TABLE'', T2.TABLE_NAME ''DB2 TABLE''
    FROM ' + @BANCO1 + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T1 
    FULL JOIN ' + @BANCO2 + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T2 
        ON T1.TABLE_NAME = T2.TABLE_NAME
    ORDER BY ISNULL(T1.TABLE_NAME, T2.TABLE_NAME)';

EXEC sp_sqlexec @SQL
```